# Issue while running multiple batch files from same batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm  trying to call second.bat file from first.bat file(Mean to say first.bat is main file which is calling second.bat  and second.bat is called one).

### first.bat

```
echo Going to call second batch file

call second.bat

echo End of first batch file.

exit 0
```

### second.bat

```
@echo off

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cmd /c start /b jre\bin\java -Djava.library.path=nativelib -classpath SampleTest.jar com.test.SampleTest argument1
```

Here the issue is when I called the second.bat from first batch file , the second.bat file is not giving control back to the first.bat file. **Its just hanging**.

I'm calling one Java process from second.bat file , after successful launching of that process the control should be go back to the first.bat and finish the rest of the activities of first.bat.

Here the control is not coming back.

Can anyone please help me that how I can achieve this scenario.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You should show us the contents of `second.bat`.

Comment: @echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cmd /c start /b jre\bin\java -Djava.library.path=nativelib -classpath SampleTest.jar com.test.SampleTest argument1

Comment: Please update your question instead of putting it a comment. StackOverFlow comments don't keep newlines.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to hazard a guess that your `Second.bat` includes a line that looks like this:

```
  java MyJavaProgram
```

If that is the case, your second `Second.bat` will not return until the java process has exited.
If you wanted to start the process before it exits, you need to start it in a new `cmd.exe`:

```
  start "" /b "java MyJavaProgram"
```

Based on the OP's update, try this:

```
start "" /b jre\bin\java -Djava.library.path=nativelib -classpath SampleTest.jar com.test.SampleTest argument1
```

Comment: Iam using the same only like cmd /c start /b jre\bin\java -Djava.library.path=nativelib -classpath SampleTest.jar com.test.SampleTest argument1

Comment: @Honey, Did you try stripping off the `cmd /c` and putting the argument to `start` inside double quotes?

Comment: Here arguement is a variable and cannot put it into a double quotes.

Comment: I have tried in your way, still no use.Any more suggestions please.

Comment: There are added title quotes in the start command, which are required when a quoted term is used in the command (and can always be added).  Try it again.  Reply with the error message if there is one.